# как решить задачу с помощью Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Помогите решить задачу используя Stream API.

Даны несколько списков`ArrayList`: `[a1, a2, ..., an]`, `[b1, b2, ..., bm]`, `[c1,c2,...,ck]`.

Задается такое условие что если **n=m=k** то мы в результате должны получить новый список который содержит комбинацию из всех элементов ранее сказанных списков, но отсортированные в следующем порядке `[a1, b1, с1, a2, b2, с2, ..., an, bm, сk]`.

Как мне это реализовать?

Вот мое решение обычным способом:

```
**public static List combine(List... lists){
    final List first = lists[0];   //результат будем складывать в первый список
    int init = first.size();       //берем размер первого списка
    int n = lists.length;          //берем кол-во списков
    int offset = 0;                //смещение соот-ет элементам из списков длина кот меньше длины наибольшего списка
    int max = init;                //длина наибольшего списка
    for (List list : lists) {
        if (max < list.size()) max=list.size();   //находим длину наибольшего списка
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {        //проходим по всем элементам с учетом длины наибольшего списка
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {      //проходим по всем спискам кроме первого
            if ( lists[j].size() <= i ) {  //проверяем что длина текущего списка не меньше текущего индекса элемента
                offset++;                  //увеличиваем смещение кот учитывает пропуски элементов из списков с наименьшей длиной
                continue;                  //пропускаем итерацию так как в текущем списке больше нет элементов
            }
            final int index = n * i + j - offset;        //индекс на кот надо вставить элемент в первый список
            if (init == max || init > i) {               //если длина первого списка наибольшая длина или больше текущего индекса i
                first.add(index, lists[j].get(i));       //добавляем соот-щий элемент из текущего списка в первый список
            } else {                                     //если у первого списка длина меньше текущего индекса i
                first.add(index - (i - init + 1), lists[j].get(i)); //учитываем что элементов из первого списка больше нет
            }
        }
    }
    return first;
}**
```

**

```
Дано четыре списка (могут быть разной длины):
[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
[b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9]
[c1]
[d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9]
На выходе получаем
[a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, d2, a3, b3, d3, a4, b4, d4, a5, b5, d5, b6, d6, b7, d7, b8, d8, b9, d9]
```

**
Я так понимаю что стандартными средствами Stream API это нельзя повторить и надо написать свой коллектор???

Comment: А если даны списки разной длины?

Comment: Показывайте код.

Comment: Как вы пытались?

Comment: если списки разной длины то в конце они не будут участвовать в чередовании элементов т е [a1,a2,a3],[b1]=>[a1,b1,a2,a3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, зачем вам Stream API для такой операции, но технически это возможно.

Проще всего создать стрим через `StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, parallel)`. Этот метод потребует для создания стрима. Spliterator - это такой продвинутый итератор, с которым я сам не очень плотно работал; насколько понимаю, этот интерфейс может разбиваться на другие spliterator, предоставляющие доступ к части коллекции, наподобие задач в Fork/Join до тех пор, пока не будет достигнут какой-то атомарный уровень. Надеюсь, я не наврал.

В свою очередь, spliterator проще всего создать через `Spliterators.spliterator(iterator, size, characteristics)` или `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, characteristics)`. В данном случае можно использовать первый вариант, но для чистоты эксперимента предположим, что работа ведется не со списками, а с итераторами неизвестной длины (это не очень хорошо для производительности, всегда лучше иметь сплитератор известной длины, но в реальной жизни часто будет встречаться именно этот вариант). Таким образом, для достижения цели надо соорудить итератор из всех имеющихся источников.

Я по-быстрому наклепал пример всего вышеописанного:

```
package me.etki.playground;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

/**
 * @author Etki {@literal <etki@etki.name>}
 * @version %I%, %G%
 * @since 0.1.0
 */
public class EntryPoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Integer> sourceA = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
        List<Integer> sourceB = Arrays.asList(10, 20);
        List<Integer> sourceC = Arrays.asList(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700);
        // ожидаемый вывод: 1 10 100 2 20 200 3 300 4 400 500 600 700

        List<Iterator<Integer>> sources = Arrays.asList(sourceA.iterator(), sourceB.iterator(), sourceC.iterator());
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = new RoundRobinIterator<>(sources);
        int characteristics = Spliterator.NONNULL | Spliterator.ORDERED;
        Spliterator<Integer> spliterator = Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, characteristics);
        Stream<Integer> stream = StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false);

        stream.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static final class RoundRobinIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

        private final List<Iterator<E>> sources;
        // not thread safe, эта часть может сильно изменяться в зависимости от требований
        // к среде выполнения и производительности
        private long cursor = 0;

        public RoundRobinIterator(Iterator<E>... sources) {
            this(Arrays.asList(sources));
        }

        public RoundRobinIterator(Collection<Iterator<E>> sources) {
            this.sources = new ArrayList<>(sources);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // есть ли в списке итератор, имеющий следующий элемент?
            return sources.stream().filter(Iterator::hasNext).findFirst().isPresent();
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            // это - кривая конструкция, но я не придумал лучше
            Iterator<E> nextSource;
            do {
                int nextIndex = (int) (cursor++ % sources.size());
                nextSource = sources.get(nextIndex);
            } while (!nextSource.hasNext());
            return nextSource.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Как видите, кода получилось много, а толку мало: безусловно, Stream API очень интересный инструмент, но иногда можно отказываться в пользу классического for просто ради сохранения количества строк.

Comment: Спасибо Ваше решение работает корректно. Не подскажите где можно почитать про создание кастомных splititerator`ов?

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov если честно, я плохо помню откуда я вообще это узнал, могу предложить только джавадоки вышеуказанных класса и интерфейса.

Answer (score 4):

```
 // Есть три списка
Collection<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
Collection<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>();
Collection<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>();

// Сгруппируем списки по их длине
Map<Integer, List<Collection<Integer>>> sizeToLists = Stream.of(a, b, c)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Collection::size));
// sizeToLists это мапа, где ключ - размер списка, а значение - списки, чья длина равна ключу.

// Если все списки, к примеру, будут длиной в 3 элемента,
// то мапа будет содержать единственный ключ - 3
// Если ключ единственный, значит все списки были одинаковой длины
final boolean lengthsAreEquals = sizeToLists.size() == 1;
if (lengthsAreEquals) {
  // Теперь превратим три списка в один отсортированный
  Stream.of(a, b, c)
      .flatMap(Stream::of) // превратим все списки в один
      .sorted()            // отсортируем
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: ВЫ НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО ПОНЯЛИ ЗАДАНИЕ!!!
Имеется в виду, что в листах могут содержаться любые наборы элементов (числа, строки, любые объекты в случайном порядке).                                                         
[a1, a2, ..., an], [b1, b2, ..., bm], [c1,c2,...,ck] - эта семантика приведена для иллюстрации порядка элементов после преобразования

Comment: groupingBy-то зачем? `.map(.size()).distinct().count() == 1`

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov на тот момент, когда я писал ответ, он точно подходил к вашему вопросу, учитесь формировать свои мысли

Comment: @Etki можно так, можно эдак. Зачем использован groupingBy - написано в ответе

Comment: там написано, что в результате будет просто мапа. но мапа и не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

сделал, и ужаснулся, не вздумай такой код в реальном продакшине использовать:

```
package stream;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Streams {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] arr1 = {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"};
    String[] arr2 = {"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8", "b9"};
    String[] arr3 = {"c1"};
    String[] arr4 = {"d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "d9"};

    System.out.println(createMagic(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4));
}

public static List<?> createMagic(Object[]... arrays) {
    int max = Stream.of(arrays).mapToInt(arr -> arr.length).max().getAsInt();
    return IntStream
            .range(0, max)
            .mapToObj(
                    index -> Stream.of(arrays)
                            .map(
                                    array -> IntStream.range(0, max)
                                            .mapToObj(
                                                    i -> i < array.length ? Optional.ofNullable(array[i]) : Optional.empty()
                                            )
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
                            )
                            .map(list -> list.get(index))
            )
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```